# Can Facebook comments plugin be closed to new comments after a certain period of time?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I'm using the Facebook comments plugin, and I would like to be able to automatically disable new comments after a certain amount of time.

In other words, once a post becomes a month old (or some other specifiable amount of time), I'd like it to continue to display existing comments, but not to allow new comments.

Does anyone know of a way to do this — perhaps by configuring the underlying Facebook settings, or by setting a meta tag on the page after the certain amount of time has passed?